# Invalid Provisioning Profile Location: Xcode 6 embeds it on submission

Tags: macos, deployment, app-store, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I upgraded last night to Xcode 6 GM. So I have an mac app which includes an helper app. I know that there should be only one provisioning profile in the package so I excluded it on the helper app. 
If I look in the .xarchive of the product it is clean from profiles (There is only one or none profile - tried both)

But for me it somehow appears that Xcode 6 GM is including the profile when you hit submit via the organizer.

[image: Submission Screen]

As you can see it adds the provisioning profile to both binaries (red rect) in the package and there is no way to avoid it.

I'm including the helper app via a Copy Ressource Build Phase to: "Contents/Library/LoginItems"

What am I doing wrong? Is this a Xcode issue or is my configuration not right?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. In XCode 5, simply not code signing the Helper app worked fine.
Now it seems like XCode is forcing it right before it uploads, so you don't get a chance to even remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a temporary solution that's far from ideal, but for now it works (unless you're on Yosemite, I'm guessing).

1. Rename XCode 6's XCode.app to something like XCode6.app
2. Download XCode 5 from the App Store (downloads as XCode.app in /Applications)
3. Open XCode 6, make SURE that you're NOT code signing the Helper app, then Archive the build and close XCode 6
4. Open XCode 5, open Organizer and proceed to Submit to Apple as usual
5. Profit!

Note: While this works, I really hope Apple fixes whatever's breaking XCode 6, as this process will most likely break with Yosemite.

**EDIT**: Submitted a bug report to Apple (rdar://18318295)

Comment: @AzzUrr1 May I ask why you need to use Xcode 6 GM for deploying an OS X app? Are you submitting Swift apps yet? BTW: On the download site for Xcode it still says "New apps and app updates submitted to the Mac App Store must be built with release versions of Xcode 5."

Comment: I did this because my machine was on 10.10 and submitting with Xcode 5 results in an error under 10.10

Answer (score 0):

This issue (*is*) seems to be fixed with Xcode 6.01

It doesn't embed an profile in the corresponding helper app:

[image]

This seems to solve the problem

Comment: @Slavik so u get The  same screen as above when submitting?

Comment: I get two provisioning profiles when I was submitting the app.

Comment: @Slavik can u pls check up your code-signing set up for your targets? For some reason my configurations isn't passing validation by now - not sure if smth changed or it didn't work before...?

Comment: I have checked them.  The same settings can pass with XCode 5.1.1 uploader.

Comment: From what I understood after talking to Apple, XCode 6 now requires all embedded binaries to be signed, so the whole Helper.app process has probably changed so that you'll actually need to include more than one embedded profile in your app.